# what is wrong with my code , at the moement to import the class?

Tags: python

I am trying to call my method hello inside my settings module, but it should work fine with `from shodan.shodan import myclass` , but it seems not to work the file structure , and importing the files and calls. this is a prototype of the exercise i am doing , but it seems not to work with classes and printing the hello method

```
.
    ├── core
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   └── settings.pyc
    ├── google
    │   ├── google.py
    │   ├── google.pyc
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   └── modules
    │       ├── images.py
    │       ├── __init__.py
    │       ├── __init__.pyc
    │       ├── utils.py
    │       └── utils.pyc
    ├── loop.sh
    ├── main.py
    ├── names
    ├── shodan
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── shodan.py
    │   └── shodan.pyc
    └── unix.sh
```

settings.py

```
from optparse import OptionParser
from sys import platform as _platform
from google.google import * 
from shodan.shodan import *

def settings(argv=None):
    if _platform == "linux" or _platform == "linux2":
    #Linux
        CrossPlatformCommandLineParser()
    elif _platform == "darwin":
    # MAC OS X
        CrossPlatformCommandLineParser()
    elif _platform == "win32":
    # Windows
        CrossPlatformCommandLineParser()
    elif _platform == "win64":
    # Windows 64-bit
        CrossPlatformCommandLineParser()

def CrossPlatformCommandLineParser(argv=None):
    if _platform == "linux" or _platform == "linux2":
    #Linux
        #print 'Linux ' + 'new cyber weapon'
        #google()
        shodan = Shodan()
        shodan.hello()
    elif _platform == "darwin":
    # MAC OS X
        print 2 
    elif _platform == "win32":
    # Windows
        print 3
    elif _platform == "win64":
    # Windows 64-bit
        print 4
```

shodan.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Shodan:
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = "aaa"

    def hello():
        print '[+] shodan...' + self.key
```

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import core.settings

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        core.settings.settings()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "interrupted by user.."
    except:
        sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this in your settings.py

Import entire shodan file. Then try to create object of a class Shodan and using that object call your hello method.

This will result into your settings.py file something like this.

```
from optparse import OptionParser
from sys import platform as _platform
from google.google import * 
import shodan.shodan

def settings(argv=None):
    if _platform == "linux" or _platform == "linux2":
    #Linux
        CrossPlatformCommandLineParser()
    elif _platform == "darwin":
    # MAC OS X
        CrossPlatformCommandLineParser()
    elif _platform == "win32":
    # Windows
        CrossPlatformCommandLineParser()
    elif _platform == "win64":
    # Windows 64-bit
        CrossPlatformCommandLineParser()

def CrossPlatformCommandLineParser(argv=None):
    if _platform == "linux" or _platform == "linux2":
    #Linux
        #print 'Linux ' + 'new cyber weapon'
        #google()
        shodanObject = shodan.Shodan("aaa")
        shodanObject.hello()
    elif _platform == "darwin":
    # MAC OS X
        print 2 
    elif _platform == "win32":
    # Windows
        print 3
    elif _platform == "win64":
    # Windows 64-bit
        print 4
```

Modify your shodan as follows :

```
class Shodan:
    """docstring for ClassName"""
    key = ""
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = "aaa"

    def hello():
        print '[+] shodan...' + self.key
```

observe the changes in settings.py for object creation as well.
shodanObject = shodan.Shodan("aaa") this particular line.

Comment: it didn't work. I tried that too , but no errors , but no showing nothing

Comment: I have added another modification in the above snippet. Please check .

Comment: I don't know why it should be displayed or if I reproduce an error don't show it.

Comment: I didn't get your last comment. Is it working or still no luck?